# create type for Eigen::Matrix in llvm

Tags: llvm, eigen

I'm trying to create a type, using llvm c++ api, for a `Eigen::Matrix <complex<double>,Dynamic, 1>` parameter.

Anyone knows how to do this?

I wrote simple sample c++ code and exposed llvm IR for it and found following lines at the beginning:

```
%"class.Eigen::Matrix" = type { %"class.Eigen::PlainObjectBase" }
%"class.Eigen::PlainObjectBase" = type { %"class.Eigen::DenseStorage" }
%"class.Eigen::DenseStorage" = type { i32*, i64 }
%"class.Eigen::DenseBase" = type { i8 }
%"class.Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase.0" = type { i8 }
%"struct.Eigen::EigenBase" = type { i8 }
%"class.Eigen::MatrixBase" = type { i8 }
%"struct.Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base" = type { i8 }
```

So I guess what I need is a `type{ type{ type{ i32*, i64 } } }`??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precise layout of a type is specified by C++ ABI. So, you may be (or may be not) lucky with defining stuff by hands....

Use LLVM's cpp backend to generate the C++ API code which will generate the given IR. This is the easiest way.

Comment: thank Anton, to be more specific, I'm trying to write a 'compiler' that 'translates' mathematical statements (given as expression trees) into llvm IR. The expression trees serve as AST for my 'compiler'. But during visiting them, I can't use simple methods like `llvm::Builder.createFAdd(L,R,"name")` because the operands are actually items of vectors of type `Eigen::Matrix<complex<double>,Dynamic,1>`. That's why I need to call methods like `Eigen::Matrix operator[]()` and `std::complex<T> operator+()`. Any idea how to accomplish this? I don't even know if it is technically doable.. Thanks again

Comment: The only way is doing from inside C++ compiler. Otherwise you won't be able to follow the ABI.